# Picture Tag doesn't resize properly on loading two sources (png and webp)

Tags: html, css, image

I'm building a website that has a 3D book:

[image: preview]

My main goal is to support a `png` and a `webp` image for all browsers. If I only load one image all is working fine:

```css
.book-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 600px;
  }
  
  @keyframes initAnimation {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY(-30deg);
    }
  }
  
  .book {
    width: 200px;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
    transition: 1s ease;
    animation: 1s ease 0s 1 initAnimation;
  }
  
  .book:hover {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  .book > :first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 320px;
    transform: translateZ(25px);
    background-color: #01060f;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #E5E4E2;
  }
  
  .book::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
    top: 3px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 314px;
    transform: translateX(172px) rotateY(90deg);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, 
      #fff 0%,
      #f9f9f9 5%,
      #fff 10%,
      #f9f9f9 15%,
      #fff 20%,
      #f9f9f9 25%,
      #fff 30%,
      #f9f9f9 35%,
      #fff 40%,
      #f9f9f9 45%,
      #fff 50%,
      #f9f9f9 55%,
      #fff 60%,
      #f9f9f9 65%,
      #fff 70%,
      #f9f9f9 75%,
      #fff 80%,
      #f9f9f9 85%,
      #fff 90%,
      #f9f9f9 95%,
      #fff 100%
      );
  }
  
  .book::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: ' ';
    width: 200px;
    height: 320px;
    transform: translateZ(-25px);
    background-color: #01060f;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 50px 10px #666;
  }
```

```html
<a 
    class="book-container"
    href="#"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noreferrer noopener">
    <div class="book">
      <img
        alt="My Cover"
        src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPyO.png"
      />
    </div>
</a>
```

But when I add the picture element to support both, the image loses the resize:

[image: preview2]

```css
.book-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 600px;
}

@keyframes initAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
}

.book {
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 initAnimation;
}

.book:hover {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.book > :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #E5E4E2;
}

.book::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 314px;
  transform: translateX(172px) rotateY(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, 
    #fff 0%,
    #f9f9f9 5%,
    #fff 10%,
    #f9f9f9 15%,
    #fff 20%,
    #f9f9f9 25%,
    #fff 30%,
    #f9f9f9 35%,
    #fff 40%,
    #f9f9f9 45%,
    #fff 50%,
    #f9f9f9 55%,
    #fff 60%,
    #f9f9f9 65%,
    #fff 70%,
    #f9f9f9 75%,
    #fff 80%,
    #f9f9f9 85%,
    #fff 90%,
    #f9f9f9 95%,
    #fff 100%
  );
}

.book::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  transform: translateZ(-25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 50px 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<a class="book-container"
        href="#"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noreferrer noopener">
    
        <div class="book">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="https://i.ibb.co/grB6NbQ/THE-BOOK-cover-image.webp" type="image/webp">
            <source srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPyO.png" type="image/png">

            <img                     
              alt="My Cover"
              src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPyO.png"/>
          </picture>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Any idea what should I change? I guess the main issue is in this part of the code:

```
.book > :first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 320px;
    transform: translateZ(25px);
    background-color: #01060f;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #E5E4E2;
  }
```

Here is the full snippet if you want to check it:

https://jsfiddle.net/p01vac52/1/

But I'm not so sure, I didn't expect that the picture element will fully break it. Or do you think it's a better idea to change the source using JS?

Comment: try  with `.book img`

Comment: Hi @dev.skas, it didn't work. I tried in all tags and as in each tag and other issues happened.

Comment: why do you need two images?

Comment: Your problem code snippet only contains the HTML and doesn't contain any CSS referencing. Please update your question to show the CSS applying to the problem.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I provided the CSS. Also, it's accessible here: https://jsfiddle.net/p01vac52/1/

The link is in the description.

Comment: **Which** image to load is based on the `srcset` values. **How** it is displayed depends on your `img` settings. Add `img { width: 100% }` to your CSS and see the difference. Take it from there...

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete yes, Stack Overflow doesn't like question code being hosted on third parties, what if JSFiddle goes down? What if JSFiddle closes? All parts of a question should be in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented,

The `srcset` attribute selects which image to load based on its size values and device specs, the `picture` / `img` elements will still need `width`/`height` values to scale the loaded image to the required size.

I added `img { width: 100% }` to make the image fit inside `.book { width: 200px; height: 320px; }`.

```css
.book-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 600px;
}

@keyframes initAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
}

.book {
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  transition: 1s ease;
  animation: 1s ease 0s 1 initAnimation;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.book:hover {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.book> :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #E5E4E2;
}

.book::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 314px;
  transform: translateX(172px) rotateY(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 0%, #f9f9f9 5%, #fff 10%, #f9f9f9 15%, #fff 20%, #f9f9f9 25%, #fff 30%, #f9f9f9 35%, #fff 40%, #f9f9f9 45%, #fff 50%, #f9f9f9 55%, #fff 60%, #f9f9f9 65%, #fff 70%, #f9f9f9 75%, #fff 80%, #f9f9f9 85%, #fff 90%, #f9f9f9 95%, #fff 100%);
}

.book::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  transform: translateZ(-25px);
  background-color: #01060f;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 50px 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<a class="book-container" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
  <div class="book">
    <picture>
      <source srcset="https://i.ibb.co/grB6NbQ/THE-BOOK-cover-image.webp" type="image/webp">
      <source srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPyO.png" type="image/png">

      <img alt="My Cover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MPyO.png" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</a>
```